# Can you choose between two classes in puppet

Tags: puppet

I have two classes in puppet and want to execute only one or the other.

Is this possible and if so how?

Thanks Guys

Comment: that is not nearly enough info to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Puppet will only consider contents of classes that are `include`d in your manifest.

```
class good_stuff {
    ...
}

class break_stuff {
    ...
}

include good_stuff
```

The above code will only apply resources from within the `good_stuff` class, not `break_stuff`.